# Facebook Application permission

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash

I have developed a Facebook application in Flash using Action-script 3. The application is working fine. I have developed Facebook login and authentication in JavaScript. The problem is then the user is not sign in to Facebook the application works fine, provide the user login panel and application permission panel and post the desire thing on user wall but if the user is already sign in than the JavaScript wont ask for the Facebook app permission and hence the app wont post on user wall. My JavaScript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var APP_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var REDIRECT_URI = "http://apps.facebook.com/engel-tanimiyorum/";
    var PERMS = 'publish_stream , email, user_birthday'; //comma separated list of extended permissions

    function init()
    {
        FB.init({appId:APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true});
        FB.getLoginStatus(handleLoginStatus);
    }

    function handleLoginStatus(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse && response.status=="connected")
        {
            
            //Show the SWF
            $('#ConnectDemo').append('<h1>You need at least Flash Player 9.0 to view this page.</h1>');
            swfobject.embedSWF("index.swf",
                "ConnectDemo", "803", "516", "9.0", null, null, null, {name:"ConnectDemo"});

        }
        else
        {
            var params = window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));
            top.location = 'http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='
                +APP_ID
                +'&scope='+PERMS
                +'&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI
                + params;
                
                

        }
        
        
    }
    $(init);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your
var PERMS = 'publish_stream , email, user_birthday';

I do believe it should be states as an Array and then you would list your permissions.
It works for me, so I think it should look like this:

public var PERMS:Array = ["publish_stream","email","user_birthday"];

Also, not having your variables public might be the problem too.

Also, from what I see, you don't have any buttons, or text input?

If not, you need to create those. Then have a click handler for when there is text in the text input it will activate a click handler that then will go to a submit post handler, which then goes to a get status handler that will show you the new status you have created.  I may be saying this all wrong.  After all, I am not using Java for my app.  But it seems logical to me that that is what you would do.